# ADB and Xcode not detect connected devices, after update to Catalina mac os

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, adb, macos-catalina

I have updated my mac mini os to Catalina. After that Android Studio and Xcode not detect connected devices. "adb devices" command not showing any devices.

But, in Android Studio, it detects my device (on troubleshoot mode). But, it was saying, not recognized as Android device. Usb debugging is already enabled. Need help on this Catalina issue.

So far I tried:

- Xcode command line tools installed.
- Xcode updated.
- Android Studio updated.
- Android SDK updated.
- Tried connecting with different cables.

Comment: You have to resetup your paths since the new shell is zshell

Comment: @NickMowen Still i haven't update my account to use zshell. In my case, ADB is listing all the emulators. But, usb connected devices are not showing. Xcode also same. Everything are workes perfectly, untill i update to Catalina.

Comment: Replacing the USB cable did it for me. My symptoms were that "adb devices" lists the status of any device as "authorizing". I have a USB hub with 4 USB-A ports connected to one of the MacBook's USB-C ports. I connect the phone thru that with a USB-A-to-USB-C cable (as well as an external keyboard and mouse). Connecting the phone directly with a USB-C-to-C cable fixed the issue. (Note that the previous setup was fine from macOS Mavericks thru Mojave on past MacBooks, and on High Sierra and Mojave on this one.)

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is from the OS, when I see the console log. I see an error

`adb@(null): AppleUSBHostUserClient::start: missing entitlement com.apple.appledfr.client`

waiting for a patch from apple

Comment: I have the same problem. same error in console. Tried everything, installing Xcode, different cables, phones etc. Does Apple know about this problem?

Comment: It's reported in Google Issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143449893

Comment: yes i also report this to apple via 
https://feedbackassistant.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

For adb it started working again, after i tried to set up the sdk path again ,

`export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk`

Comment: Did you use Bash or Zsh?

Comment: i am using zsh @VisuddhaKarunaratne

Comment: In my case, ADB is listing all the emulators. But, usb connected devices are not showing. Xcode also same. Everything are workes perfectly, untill i update to Catalina.

Comment: it seems if you use zsh, you have to set android home every time you boot up your pc, in that case switching to bash is better.

Comment: Switching to zsh didn't help.

Comment: copy all env data from .bash_profile to .zshrc file, if you are planning to use zsh as your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I did the "**Revoke USB debugging authorizations**" from the Developer options on the phone and **run Xcode** so it would install some updates.

Once I did that, it offered up the usual "did you want to allow debugging on this device" option, and everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Using zsh, I added

`ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk`

to my .zprofile file (if you don't have one, just create it with `touch .zprofile` in your home directory) and rebooted.

Comment: You might need to create it.

Answer (score 1):

After Mac OSX is upgraded, then open Xcode to install the components. Then connect your android phone through USB rather than double type-c. After that, do the "Revoke USB debugging authorizations" from the Developer options on the phone. Then adb devices list will show the connected phone.

Answer (score 1):

1) go to and install www.android.com/filetransfer
2) then revoke the USB debugging authorizations on android device
3) make sure you are running the old bash (in Catalina), to do this: chsh -s /bin/bash
4) unplug Android device from USB cable
5) restart Mac Catalina
6) plug back in Android device
7) run terminal (bash)
8) adb devices
it should show up, note: I had tried to run the Android File Transfer app after installing it, but it never would run. With that said, it seems to try and run something when it detects the cable being plugged in. Disclaimer: I don't know if this will work for you, but these are the steps I ran through to get it to work for me